# Delphi: How to fix wrong SdkTransformAssistant iOS header conversion?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, delphi

The headers for the [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios) has been converted using SDKTransformAssistant in [this repository](https://github.com/FMXExpress/FacebookSDKs-iOS-Object-Pascal).
Unfortunately, they have not been converted correctly by the tool. `FBSDKShareLinkContent` is supposed to inherit from `FBSDKSharingContent` so it contains the property `contentURL`, but it doesn't.

What is the correct way to fix the pascal header?

The Objective C headers:

```
@protocol FBSDKSharingContent <FBSDKCopying, NSSecureCoding>
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSURL *contentURL;
@property (nonatomic, copy) FBSDKHashtag *hashtag;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *peopleIDs;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *placeID;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *ref;

@interface FBSDKShareLinkContent : NSObject <FBSDKSharingContent>
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *contentDescription;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *contentTitle;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *contentTitle;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSURL *imageURL;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *quote;
- (BOOL)isEqualToShareLinkContent:(FBSDKShareLinkContent *)content;
```

How they are currently converted:

```
  FBSDKSharingContent = interface(IObjectiveC)
    ['{BF1DBAD7-9326-44AA-A6BD-5E7F0515F925}']
    procedure setContentURL(contentURL: NSURL); cdecl;
    function contentURL: NSURL; cdecl;
    procedure setHashtag(hashtag: FBSDKHashtag); cdecl;
    function hashtag: FBSDKHashtag; cdecl;
    procedure setPeopleIDs(peopleIDs: NSArray); cdecl;
    function peopleIDs: NSArray; cdecl;
    procedure setPlaceID(placeID: NSString); cdecl;
    function placeID: NSString; cdecl;
    procedure setRef(ref: NSString); cdecl;
    function ref: NSString; cdecl;
  end;

  FBSDKShareLinkContent = interface(NSObject)
    ['{09744C48-BB8F-49AB-A42E-F2E2C2C6129E}']
    procedure setContentDescription(contentDescription: NSString); cdecl;
    function contentDescription: NSString; cdecl;
    procedure setContentTitle(contentTitle: NSString); cdecl;
    function contentTitle: NSString; cdecl;
    procedure setImageURL(imageURL: NSURL); cdecl;
    function imageURL: NSURL; cdecl;
    procedure setQuote(quote: NSString); cdecl;
    function quote: NSString; cdecl;
    function isEqualToShareLinkContent(content: FBSDKShareLinkContent): Boolean; cdecl;
  end;

  TFBSDKShareLinkContent = class(TOCGenericImport<FBSDKShareLinkContentClass, FBSDKShareLinkContent>)
  end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these lines from FBSDKSharingContent to FBSDKShareLinkContent:

```
procedure setContentURL(contentURL: NSURL); cdecl;
function contentURL: NSURL; cdecl;
```